# Android: Rotating Button on a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, runnable

Could someone provide a sample implementation for rotating a button on a thread ? As of now I am rotating my button on the UI thread using the following code:

```
Animation ranim = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),
                    R.anim.rotation);
                buttonRotate.setAnimation(ranim);
```

Comment: are you saying you would like to use a thread to rotate the button?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do.

Comment: Your gonna have a heck of a time rotating the button in a runnable since everything has to go back to the UI thread to update

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is NOT what you want to do. Can you please give some more Context.

Comment: Background threads cannot manipulate the UI elements. Though I have not personally tested, I would assume that this would include applying animations. Thus I don't think what you are wanting to do is going to be possible.

Comment: Basically I am processing some data in my UI thread and I want my Button to rotate while this data is being processed. So I figured using a thread to rotate the button would solve my problem

Comment: Reverse your logic.  Do the data processing on a background thread and rotate the button directly on the main (UI) thread.  You cannot (and should not) manipulate views from a background thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following should work for you.

```
Thread thread = new Thread() 
{ 
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        try { 
                Animation ranim = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), 
                R.anim.rotation); 
                buttonRotate.setAnimation(ranim); 
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}; 

thread.start();
```

you might eventually have to create an `AsyncTask` which can run independently without disturbing `UI Thread`.

Comment: That still makes the button rotate after the data is processed

Comment: i would recommend that you process your data through `AsyncTask` and rotate the button on `UI Thread`. The logic is that it's a `UI Task` and you can pass it on to a `worker Thread` but that `worker Thread` eventually have to take that task to `UI Thread` and get it processed. But doing data process through `AsyncTask` will let a `worker Thread` do all the data processing while `UI Thread` rotates button.

Answer (score 0):

in your UI thread define

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler();
```

then inside your thread, use this:

```
mainHandler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
       //your piece of code
    }
});
```

This has served me well so far in several cases, hope it does for you too! :D

EDIT:

```
mainHandler.post(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
            while(someBoolean==true)
            {
                //your piece of code
            }
    }
});
```

if you'd define 'someBoolean' inside your class, just like you did with the handler, the thread is supposed to get it, I believe.
this way, after processing your data, simply set someBoolean to false, and the rotating stops.

Comment: I think This is still going to post the runnable to the UI thread. You'd have to create a Thread object instead of Runnable to get it off of the UI thread.

Comment: that's what it is supposed to do, what I understood from his question, is that he wants to manipulate the UI inside another thread

Comment: I basically want the button to rotate while the data is being processed. Will this allow me to do that ?

Comment: no, this allows you to rotate the button only once WHILE the data is being processed in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have access to my IDE at the moment, so I am going to list the steps for you rather that put buggy code up here.

1) Implement "AnimationListener" in the same class that extends Activity.
2) Set a click listener on your button.
3) Create an AsyncTask class.
4) Override doInBackground (of AsyncTask) and place your resource intensive logic there.
5) In onAnimationStart (of AnimationListener), implement the logic to call your AsyncTask, i.e. new MyTask().execute();
6) Define the animation and set it to your button.

This is how it should go:  You click the button, onAnimationStart is called, your AsyncTask logic and animation both start.  This way you can have your button rotate at the same that that your background thread is performing resource intensive operations - i.e. concurrently.

And just for fun, you may want to disable your button from being clicked again before the background task has finished.

Sorry for the lack of code, but this should be pretty straight forward from here.